# How to limit MemoryStream length?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to pass a Stream object to an API that will serialize some data into the stream. I don't know the amount of data in advance, and I don't have any control over that code. However, I want to limit the stream size by a certain number. Can I make MemoryStream throw an exception when its Length reaches a specified limit? Something like this:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(...); // I want to specify MaxLength=10 somehow...

for (byte i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    stream.WriteByte(i); // ok

stream.WriteByte(10); // this should throw
```

One way to achieve this behavior is to override SetLength, Seek, Write, and WriteByte methods (anything else?).

Is there any easier or better way to do this? Am I missing any existing constructors or properties?

Comment: What's the API you're calling? Is it unmanaged?

Comment: It is managed. Also, we can assume that the exception thrown by the stream will be handled appropriately. This is just another internal part of our project, so the name of the API will not tell you anything. Technically, we could even change the API so that it accepts the maximum length as a parameter, but I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: You can do something like new MemoryStream(new byte[xxx]) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[10]);
for (byte i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    ms.WriteByte(i); // ok

ms.WriteByte(10);
```

Throws `NotSupportedException`, with "Memory stream is not expandable."

Comment: Thank you, this looks simple enough and can definitely work in some contexts. In my case, however, I expect most of the streams to be just a few bytes long, and only occasionally they would grow up to a few megabytes (the actual limit I want to put there is about 10M). On top of that, this code will be called concurrently from multiple threads, so preallocating this amount of memory is out of the question in my case.

Answer (score 2):

If your memory restriction is very high so you can't (or don't want to) pre-allocate the array you can simply wrap the MemoryStream in custom Stream-based class that will do length checking on write.

Please note that if you expect large amount of data to be written to MemoryStream (80Kb+) you may need to verify if memory usage pattern and performance of MemoryStream is acceptable for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you provided is the simplest.
You can create your own stream that inherits from MemoryStream and has a constructor that takes the desired length as parameter. Then you only need to implement some extra logic in the Write methods and after that call the base.Write/WriteByte().